# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant

Tags: android, jackson, esri

In my android application I have one [library project](http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/) that uses [MicrosoftSyncFramework](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e). This library project include `jackson-mini-1.9.10.jar`

And I am using [ESRI arcgis](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/) Map that include following jars

1. arcgis-android-api.jar
2. jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.5.jar
3. jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.5.jar
4. jcifs-1.3.17.jar

Now as library projects have different jackson jar I am getting following exception

`Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant;`

As jar are not same so I can not remove any jar. Please suggest if we can set any priority.

see below images

1. Android app with ESRI map:-

[image: Android app with ESRI map]

2. microsoftSyncFrameworkToolkit library project:-

   [image: microsoftSyncFrameworkToolkit library project]

Comment: if jackson-core contains all of the functionalities of the jackson-mini, perhaps you can move jackson-core jar into the library project.

Comment: I can put or remove jar microsoftSyncFrameworkToolkit library project only but I tried all way even I put all .java files as src.  but nothing happens.

Comment: is my solution solved your problem?

Comment: No, as i show you i didn't include jar in build path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this error by configuring build path of library project. I unchecked `private Library` refer following screen shots [image]

Answer (score 0):

Then remove one jar from the build path but keep that one in libs i hope it works.

Comment: I can not remove see, I include images of app structure